# Table view rows are rendered on top of a view that is in front of them in the hierarchy

Tags: macos, calayer, nstableview, nsview, appkit

I have an app that displays a table view with information, and I want to draw a time indicator in a view on top of the entire table view, similar to Xcode’s Instruments.

So I have the following hierarchy:

```
|-superview
|\
| |-table view
|  \
|   |-row view
|   |-row view
|   |-row view
|   |-row view
 \
  |-timeline indicator view (wantsLayer=YES)
```

The timeline indicator view is inserted as a subview to the table view’s superview, and is ordered above the table view. On each `viewDidLayout` call, I reorder it to be above the table view.

It works well for rows that are visible at first:
[image]

(The dashed line is rendered in the timeline indicator view.)

But when I scroll the table view, the rows are somehow drawn on top of the timeline indicator view:
[image]

Looking at Xcode’s hierarchy inspector, I see all the views are ordered correctly, as described above, and the timeline indicator view is supposed to be on top of the table view and all its subviews:

[image]

I am primarily familiar with iOS technologies, so I am a little perplexed what might be causing this rendering issue.

Comment: How do you know if the rows are drawn over the line, do you see the line appear and disappear? Is the time indicator view a floating subview?

Comment: If I collapse the bottom pane, I see the line continue below the two rows. So just these two rows are rendered somehow above.

Comment: Did you add the timeline indicator in code? I don't know if `NSScrollView` and `NSClipView` support an extra view. Is the table view still the document view? Did you try `addFloatingSubview:forAxis:` of `NSScrollView`?

Comment: The indicator is added in code, but is not added as a subview to the scroll view or clip view. It is added to the scroll view’s superview.

Comment: Do the table view, the row views and their superview have a layer?

Comment: Interestingly, enabling `wantsLayer` on the superview of the tableview, the one that contains the indicator view, seems to solve the issue, as well as other benefits. But that still leaves the question of why this is still possible.

Comment: BTW, this happens on macOS Sierra and macOS High Sierra beta 1.